# Domain object and infrastructure dependency

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

We have a domain object (let's say a plane) and business flow (stateMachine object). on an event (failure) we want to change the state from flying to falling. and don't know what's the best way to model it.
i don't want to make method `plane.setState()` because it should be the internal state of the plane

other option is to use springs @Configurable to inject stateMachine into the plane and create method `plane.failure()` but it requires an jvm agent and it probably doesn't work very well with eclipse and unit tests

3rd option is to make method `plane.failure(stateMachine)` looks ugly but seems to work

any other ideas?

Comment: why not be explicit and do `Plane.HandleFailure()` and have `Plane` class maintain state?

Comment: because it's complicated. if i do it manually, i'll end up with thousands of 'if' statement. i want to use the tool that lets me create a workflow declaratively

Comment: so are there different kinds of failure?

Comment: yes, that's a typical state machine. when the state is flying then failure will change the state to falling. when state is 'preparing to start' then failure will change state to 'immediate check required'. when state is 'scrapped' then failure has no business sense. and of course 'failure' is not the only event, there are others:'take off', 'start engine' etc

Comment: if the tool you're using to provide a state machine can be regarded as a domain service, then the 3rd option is perfectly fine. another would be to simply model the state machine as value objects inside the Plane entity.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to expose the `State` of the object externally by a `setState()` method then you need somehow to communicate the `Event` to it via say an `eventOccured(Event)` method. From that point onwards it's internal matters of the object to set its own *State* according to the *Event* occured. Pressumably both *State* and *Event* are some sort of enums and the *State* enum is internally defined in the domain object. I would even consider extracting the *State* enum logic and transistions in an intermediate abstract class.